# How to amend expected status codes in Visual Studio Web Performance Tests

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, web-testing

How do you *(or even can you)* amend the expected HTTP status codes in a Visual Studio Web Performance Test?

I'm checking some new bits of a clients site, so using some Visual Studio Web Performance Tests to drive the pages.

Run the tests and the expected actions occur on the server ... **BUT** the tests are failing

The reason is there are a few hidden links to some missing GIF files, which are returning a 404 status

I can't get the client to add the files, but I don't want to check the various tests each time to check whether the **"fail"** is one of the expected 404's, or a real fail

Comment: Is your question answered? If not then what else is wanted?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the request you can change "Expected HTTP Status Code" to the expected (Int32) Http Status Code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of expecting a different status code you can write a web test plugin that removes dependant requests. Basically the plugin scans the dependant requests and any that match some criteria are removed. I have done this on a few performance test projects to avoid getting test failures for things that I know would fail every test. Of course your test report should describe the missing files. See also See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2008/07/17/dependent-request-filter.aspx